# Code from codepen.io not working when downloaded: floorplan

Tags: javascript, local, web-deployment

I downloaded the code from `codepen.io` and it does not work locally.

http://codepen.io/nanarth/pen/raarXe

I suspect that references to some libraries are not exported, but can figure out which.

Can anyone help me with this (I am new to this)

Thank you

UPDATE: Added the following code. Still not working

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Floor Plan - local coordinate map layers for D3.js</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.13/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://codepen.io/nanarth/pen/yyyqdL"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Update #2: The screenshot of the error I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: floor plan is not displayed

Comment: You have any errors in console shown?

Comment: I add the screenshot to show the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what happens, is when then files are exported, one of the files is for some reason empty.

replacing

```
<script src='js/yyyqdl.js'></script>
```

with

```
<script src='http://codepen.io/nanarth/pen/yyyqdL.js'></script>
```

solved the issue.

Or the file can be downloaded and used locally and keep the old reference

Answer (score 4):

You're right, this pen is including external JS libs. Here's quick gif How to get there.

[image: quick gif how to get to included libs]

Comment: I update the code and added resources- still not working. I update the question to reflect changes.

Comment: there is some error in the console. Missing libraries is not the issue

Answer (score 1):

Those errors You got mean that jQuery libraries are not defined by the time that code runs. Ensure that:

- You have copied JS code from the right pane in codepen
- You have copied inline JS code from the left (html) pane in codepen
- You wrap javascript in [jQuery ready function](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)